# having problem in adding object key to the object generating asynchronously

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm getting two objects runnningGame and runningGameTime from two asynchronous calls. The objects are:

```
    {
  numberOfBets: 0,
  totalAmountCollected: 0,
  amountDistributed: 0,
  finished: false,
  _id: 60f52b621bcef84190024cfd,
  gameId: 60f52b621bcef84190024cfb,
  allPlayerBettedBetId: [],
  createdAt: 2021-07-19T07:36:02.240Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-07-19T07:36:02.240Z,
  __v: 0
}
{
  startTime: 2021-07-19T07:36:02.235Z,
  _id: 60f52b621bcef84190024cfb,
  gameType: 'Slow Parity',
  endTime: 2021-07-19T07:39:02.235Z,
  createdAt: 2021-07-19T07:36:02.237Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-07-19T07:36:02.237Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

and I'm doing these operations

```
try {
    let runningGame = await model.findOne({ finished: false });
    const runnigGameTime = await Game.findById(runningGame.gameId);
    const finishedGameDetails = await model.finishedGames();
    runningGame.endTime = finishedGameDetails.endTime;
    console.log(runningGame);
    res.send();
    // res.send({runningGameDetails:{endTime:runnigGameTime.endTime,startTime:runnigGameTime.startTime,runningGame},finishedGameDetails});
}
catch (error)
{
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).send({ error });
}
```

but in try block at 4th line is not executing I'm getting the same runningGame object even after adding the endTime to it. What is the problem here??????????

Comment: pls provide more information: what's your `model` and `model.finishedGames`?

Comment: without saving command,why not same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because findOne() returns a mongoose document model. In order to add the endTime property you want it as a plain JS object, which can be done using the [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean).

```
let runningGame = await model.findOne({ finished: false }).lean();
```